# how to make the font of the table tiny or footnote size

Tags: tables

when I would like to make all the content of a table  tiny, i m obliged  to do like that;

```
\begin{table}[l]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lll|lllllllllllllllll}
\cline{4-20}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tiny}$Selected~area$\end{tiny}{\vrule width 0pt height 1.25em\begin{tiny}$$\end{tiny}}}&\begin{tiny}C\end{tiny}&  \begin{tiny}O\end{tiny}&\begin{tiny}Si\end{tiny}&\begin{tiny}   V   \end{tiny}&\begin{tiny}Cr\end{tiny} &\begin{tiny}Fe\end{tiny}   &\begin{tiny}Mo\end{tiny}\\
\hline
```

Is there any way please to do it easiely? with a simple command !!

Comment: For the future, please mark your code as code. This is done highlighting the code in the editor and hitting the "{}"-button. Please provide a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050), that begins at `\documentclass` and ends at `\end{document}`, providing all code to reproduce your issue but not more than that!

Comment: ok tahnk you  Im sorry

Comment: I'd advise against typing a whole table in tiny font size, unless you want your table not to be read. You don't explain what is your problem, but I'm sure there's plenty of other solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Leave out all those `\begin{tiny}`s and `\end{tiny}`s. Instead use `\tiny` once prior to `\begin{tabular}` inside the `table`-environment.

```
\documentclass[]{article}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
{\tiny
\begin{tabular}{lll|lllllllllllllllll}
\cline{4-20}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$Selected~area${\vrule width 0pt height 1.25em}}&C&  O&Si&   V   &Cr &Fe   &Mo\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Also you should not use `$` for this `Selected-area` if it is only to display that italic. For that use `\textit{Selected-area}`. If it should contain math everything is fine with that. And don't use `$$` as an empty inline math. `$$` does something different from that.

Comment: not that it is needed but `$$` does make an empty inline math list in a tabluar `l` cell.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but outside of a `tabular` it doesn't, so I wouldn't use it in it, but thanks for the information.

Comment: I don't think the extra pair of braces (`{\tiny ...}`) is needed, the `table` environment forms a group, so `\tiny` wont affect anything outside it.

Comment: that does not work

Comment: @Skillmon nothing to do with tabular, try `\mbox {abc $$ xyz}`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I've added them just to be sure but you're right, they are not necessary in this case.

Comment: @SeifFetni what do you mean, "does not work"? It is working flawlessly on my machine. Could you post an MWE using my `table` environment that does not work?

Comment: DavidCarlisle  : before begin tabluar?

Comment: skillmon  : I tried it in a simple test.tex  file, that works

Comment: @SeifFetni the simplest test file is my complete answer and there it works, so please, provide the code where it doesn't.

Comment: I identified the origin of the problem, it is due to a bad command :\let\oldtabular=\tabular
\def\tabular{\small\oldtabular}

Comment: just a last question for the future , how to make to insert a code in a comment or in the main question?

Comment: @SeifFetni See [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for instructions on how to use the editor (and a bit more). And if it answers your question you might accept my answer (the green tick) -- I don't think you'll get more/better answers for that.

Answer (score 0):

i would type this example as:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{lll|lllllllllllllllll}
\textit{Selected area}  & C & O & Si & V & Cr & Fe & Mo    \\
\cline{1-3}
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]